# Empty tag list for existing repository with JGit

Tags: java, git, jgit

I have cloned a git repository through a `CloneCommand` of JGit and now I'm trying to get the list of tags that I'm going to checkout. However when I execute

```
Git git = Git.wrap(clonedRepository);
List<Ref> tagsList = git.tagList().call();
```

And then a `tagsList.size()`, it returns `0`. The cloned repository was setup `true` to clone all branches and it was not bare cloned. When I check my `.git` folder in the path `refs/tags/` I find all the tags I need to checkout.

Here I add more details about how I cloned the remote repository:

```
File path = new File(localPath);
path.delete();

FileRepositoryBuilder builder = new FileRepositoryBuilder();
clonedRepository = builder.setGitDir(path).readEnvironment().findGitDir().build();

CloneCommand clone = Git.cloneRepository();

clone.setBare(false);
clone.setCloneAllBranches(true);
clone.setDirectory(path).setURI(remotePath);
clone.setCredentialsProvider(new UsernamePasswordCredentialsProvider(username, password));
clone.call();
```

Where `localPath = "./target/ClonedRepository"` and `remotePath` is my git address (http).

Comment: Are you sure that `clonedRepository` points to the right repository (check `clonedRepository.getDirectory()` in doubt)? What does `git tag -l` show?

Comment: `clonedRepository.getDirectory()` returns `.\target\ClonedRepository` which is the folder that contains the `.git` for the project. When I execute  `git tag -l` inside that path, it shows the whole list of tags.

Comment: `clonedRepository.getDirectory()` should return the path to the metadata directory (i.e. the `.git` dir). Please post the code that creates `cloneRepository` instance.

Comment: @RüdigerHerrmann I already posted the code.

Comment: Your `FileRepositoryBuilder` code doesn't look right. Besides it happens **before** the repo is cloned when tehre is no repo yet. Why don't you use the `Git` instance returned by `clone.call()`?

Comment: It solved my problem. clonedRepository was never pointing to the cloned git project.

Answer (score 0):

`clonedRepository` was not pointing to the repository path I wanted to (the local cloned one). The following lines of code solved this issue:

```
Git git = clone.call();
clonedRepository = git.getRepository();
```

In this sense, `clonedRepository` points to the `.git` that contains all the tags of the project. Then I can get the map for these tags by executing

```
tagsMap = clonedRepository.getTags();
```

Where the type for `tagsMap` variable is `Map <String, Ref>` (see [reference](http://download.eclipse.org/jgit/docs/jgit-2.0.0.201206130900-r/apidocs/org/eclipse/jgit/lib/Repository.html#getTags())).